# SQL conditional INNER JOIN with two different tables

Tags: sql, inner-join, multiple-tables

I have a following simplified sub-query that should be executed first:

```
(SELECT app.recordId, left(userid,1) userid, count(*)FROM
      app group by userid,recordId) y
```

Based on the result of this subquery, if `userid='A'` I would like to INNER JOIN with `tableA`, `If userid='B'`, I'd like to INNER JOIN with `tableB`.

I also want the result of both inner joins to appear. Is there a way so that I can do this without re-executing the subquery to minimize the execution time?

Comment: The GROUP BY clause in the sub-query/derived table is incorrect. Should be `group by left(userid,1),recordId`. Also please clarify what you mean by "I also want the result of both inner joins to appear".

Comment: @PaxBin Try `FROM table t Left join TableA on t.userid ='A' Left join TableB on t.userid = 'B'`

Comment: Please provide your actual table structures, example data, and expected output. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @TT. . . . Some databases support this syntax, although the OP should be clear about the database being used by properly tagging the question.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Oh, good point. I'm always assuming it's TSQL... heh =)

Comment: Looks like a very bad database design when you have to use LEFT on an ID column.

Comment: So what columns would you show from table A or B? Would you have, say two columns one of which would be null, or one column filled either with an A or B value?

Comment: @TT. yes, i made the error writing the query here, you are right, i should have used group by left(userid,1)

Comment: @ThorstenKettner a very abd design, now its up to me to deal with this mess

Comment: @ThorstenKettner, sorry i didn't write the columns needed in my question, i was just showing the problem that i'm facing and asking for the logic to use

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to use `left join` twice, probably with `coalesce()`:

```
SELECT y.*, COALESCE(a.col1, b.col1) as col1
FROM (SELECT app.recordId, left(userid, 1) as userid, count(*) as cnt
      FROM app
      GROUP BY recordId, left(userid, 1)
     ) y LEFT JOIN
     tableA a
     ON y.userId = 'A' and . . . LEFT JOIN
     tableB b
     ON y.userId = 'B' and . . .
WHERE y.userId IN ('A', 'B');
```

The `. . .` is space for additional join conditions, which the question does not specify.

EDIT:

If you want to filter out rows that have no matches (ala an "inner join" approach):

```
WHERE y.userId IN ('A', 'B') and not (a.col is null and b.col is null)
```

where `a.col` and `b.col` are two columns used for the `join` condition.

Comment: The `WHERE` clause can be used to make those joins more "inner" by asserting the correct join has occurred e.g. `(y.userId = 'A' and a.nonnullablecolumn IS NOT NULL) or (y.userId='B' and b.nonnullablecolumn IS NOT NULL)`

Comment: the left join approach would work, but i'll still have result that do not have a match on both tables, which an inner join would have not shown

Comment: @gordon-linoff maybe the best appraoch to use is to store the result of the subquery in a temporary table and reuse it for both joins along with an union betwee the two queries

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say how you want the columns from the tables A and B to be handled. We also don't know how the tables are related. So all I can give you is an example.

Let's say you want a description that either comes from table A or B:

```
select agg.userid, a_and_b.description, agg.recordid, agg.rec_count
from 
(
  select left(userid,1) as userid, recordid, count(*) as rec_count
  from app
  group by left(userid,1), recordid
) agg
join
(
  select 'A' as userid, recordid, description from a
  union all
  select 'B' as userid, recordid, description from b
) a_and_b on a_and_b.userid = agg.userid and a_and_b.recordid = agg.recordid;
```